# Add some string on a set of strings

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that passes a data like this

111,222,333,444,555 (Dynamic means 1 or more set of numbers)

All of the strings above are encapsulated in one string. here is the stored procedure

`call sp_concat('111,222,333,444,555');`

Now here is what I need. How can i convert that string on the following forms

`a.111,a.222,a.333,a.444,a.555`

`'111','222','333','444','555'`

2 set of functions that will do the output above in mysql stored proc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a combination of `REPLACE` and `CONCAT` for both.  For the first:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT('a.', REPLACE('111,222,333,444,555', ',', ',a.')) AS first
FROM dual;
```

For the second:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT('''', REPLACE('111,222,333,444,555', ',', ''','''), '''') AS second
FROM dual;
```

### Demo

Comment: sir question for the second how about this kind of symbol "`" or what they call grave accent

Comment: because the second is for the select

Comment: @NardongBagsik AFAIK backticks don't require any special escaping, i.e. `SELECT '\`' AS backtick FROM dual` is completely valid.

Comment: actualy sir i will use the second one a column for my insert into

Comment: i get an error if there no back tiks in my column in insert

Comment: Insert?  I don't see an insert anywhere in your question, and obviously I can't read your mind.  You should probably open a new question as the above has already been answered.

Comment: sir here is the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50172993/how-to-add-backticks-on-a-set-of-string