# How to add backticks on a set of string

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a string that looks like this.

`111,222,333,444,555`

how can i add back ticks on each data? I will use it for insert columns.

I tried this one

`SELECT
    CONCAT('''', REPLACE('111,222,333,444,555', ',', ''','''), '''') AS second
FROM dual;`

but it does not support back ticks.

Heres what Im trying to do. I pass a set of string on a stored procedure and the use that as my column when i am trying to insert a data in a table

Comment: You should tell us what you are trying to do.  What does the insert query look like?

Comment: sir edited my question

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT('`', REPLACE('111,222,333,444,555', ',', '`,`'), '`') AS second
FROM dual;
```

**Output:**

```
second
`111`,`222`,`333`,`444`,`555`
```